# How to render json for more than one outer join tables with 'includes' option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a outer join active record. i need to display json for the outer join query.
This is the active record i have written

`@recent_details=Property.includes(:space_amenities,:event_suitabilities,:purpose_suitabilities,:venue_categories).where(id: params[:id])
 respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render :json => @recent_details.to_json(include: :venue_categories)}
end`

here in json part, with include option i included only one outer join table. i need to include all these 4(:space_amenities,:event_suitabilities,:purpose_suitabilities,:venue_categories) tables in include option. how to include all these while rendering json.

Any help is appreiatable.

Comment: ya got result :) working fine :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
format.json { render :json => @recent_details.to_json(:include=> [:space_amenities,:event_suitabilities,:purpose_suitabilities,:venue_categories]‌​)}
```